# Snaplet to SnapletLens (snaplet initialization)

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

In function `app :: SnapletInit App App` I tried my snaplet that has couple of fields:

```
m <- nestSnaplet "mys" mys $ myexInit  -- Data Myex = Myex {_foo :: Text, ...}
```

and later in the same function:

```
let txt1 = myFun  m    -- myFun :: Myex -> Text
```

Compiler says:

```
Couldn't match expected type `SnapletLens a0 b0'
            with actual type `Snaplet Myex'
```

I tried to define a `SnapletLens` with

```
class MyLens b where
  myLens :: SnapletLens b Myex
```

but then the question is, is this the approach when to get or set the contents of myex-snaplet? And how to refer to the fields of myex? I tried several things, like

```
let txt = (foo . myLens) m
```

But they didn't work in the app method. So the problem is, how to access the fields of Snaplet `Myex`? In the `myFun` the use of lenses is straightforward, or at least everything compiles.

I just saw another answer that looks very similar. 
[Use subsnaplet during snaplet initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308326/how-to-use-subsnaplet-during-snaplet-initialization?rq=1)

However, if I replace

```
let txt1 = myFun  m    -- myFun :: Myex -> Text
```

with

```
let txt1 = foo  m
```

Compiler says now:

```
Couldn't match expected type `T.Text -> f0 T.Text'
            with actual type `Snaplet Myex'
```

I assumed that in the above link the `pgPool` is a lens to `pgs`.

br gsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can get a `Myex` from a `Snaplet Myex`.  The [Snaplet](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.11.2/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet.html#t%3aSnaplet) type has a [Comonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad/3.0.1.1/doc/html/Control-Comonad.html#t%3aComonad) instance, which means that you can use the [extract](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad/3.0.1.1/doc/html/Control-Comonad.html#v%3aextract) function.  Alternatively, if you don't want to import Control.Comonad, you can use the [snapletValue](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.11.2/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet.html#v%3asnapletValue) lens.

```
m :: Snaplet Myex
view snapletValue m :: Myex
```

Comment: Thank you! Both worked and I was able to build this in the way that's natural to me. (I already started to think, if the whole thing could be restated in some other way.) Anyhow, I think that it's better to try to learn something about comonads before finding alternative solutions...

Comment: You don't really have to understand much about comonads for this.  All you need to know is that a comonad is a container (of type `w a`) from which you can extract something (of type `a`).  Here you are simply using the `extract` function as an accessor to get the `Myex` stored inside the `Snaplet Myex` data type.